# Command-line/API for Schema Compare in SSDT SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: database, api, command-line, synchronization, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio 2012, we have [`Schema Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in [SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)'s `SQL Server Database Project` (DbProject) project which helps

1. Compare `source` versus `target`
2. Update `target` to make it the same as `source`

Where

1. Source and target can be either a database, a DbProject project, or a .dacpac file
2. Update can be done via an **update action** or **generated script**

My question is that is it possible to have and where can I get the command-line/API interface to call this feature?

Answer (score 60):

**SOURCE Database**

`sqlpackage.exe /a:Extract /scs:Server=%Server%;Database=AspBaselineDB; /tf:%DriveSpec%\%DacPath%\%AspBaselineDB%_baseline.dacpac`

**TARGET Database**

`sqlpackage.exe /a:Extract /scs:Server=%Server%;Database=%AspTargetDB-2%; /tf:%DriveSpec%\%DacPath%\%AspTargetDB%.dacpac`

**COMPARE & GENERATE the Delta script**

`sqlpackage.exe /a:Script /sf:%DriveSpec%\%DacPath%\%AspBaselineDB%_baseline.dacpac 
/tf:%DriveSpec%\%DacPath%\AspNetDb\%AspTargetDB%.dacpac /tdn:aspTargetdb /op:%DriveSpec%\%SqlPath%\AspNetDb\AspDbUpdate.sql`

**EXECUTE the script**

`sqlcmd.exe -S %Server%\aspnetdbAmexDev -i %DriveSpec%\%SqlPath%\AspNetDb\AspDbUpdate.sql`

I do this in CMD scripting as our IT dept will not allow unsigned PowerShell scripts and they won't purchase a cert. This works flawlessly, even when calling it from TFS 2012 Team Builds or simply executing the .CMD script from a VS command prompt as Administrator.

**Note!**

Add the following SET in your script: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin`

Also: as you can see I set path variables. I do this as I am touching up to 50 flavors of the database and this is the only consistent way I have found to generate delta scripts and update our DEV and TEST databases.

Comment: Can we also compare specific user table(s) data and generate the script?

Comment: is there any way to do this for a certain table, or item? Schema Compare in Visual Studio and Update will allow people to manually pick and choose, how do I do this in command line?

Answer (score 3):

At present, the only way to get API access to schema compare results is by writing a deployment plan modifier/executor that runs during a deploy/script operation in the DacServices API. This lets you examine the deployment plan generated when comparing a dacpac against a database, but it also gives access to the [ModelComparisonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.deployment.modelcomparisonresult.aspx) that represents a schema compare operation, which is available in the context object passed to the [OnExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.deployment.deploymentplancontributor.onexecute.aspx) method of a contributor. I've just written a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx) that covers this process and might be useful to you - take a look at that and hopefully it'll help you get started.

Comment: Need a nice powershell one liner to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a few lines](http://blogs.southworks.net/mcabral/2012/02/07/deploying-database-command-line/) on this topic a while ago. Hopefully you find them useful.

In a nutshell, the tool you are looking for is `vsdbcmd.exe`, which is distributed by Ultimate and Premium versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Cool! This seems to be the one I need.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. VSDbCmd.exe seems to be for Visual Studio 2010 right?

Comment: It is unlikely to be available for Visual Studio 2012 as mentioned here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/629c9d6d-2de0-44f3-8043-52f71530c844/will-vsdbcmdexe-be-available-in-future-releases-of-visual-studio-2012

Comment: SqlPackage is an updated version of vsdbcmd.exe. It has equivalent functionality. @NamG.VU - you said in response to a previous answer that SqlPackage wouldn't help, but here you say that vsdbcmd would? What exact feature do you need that SqlPackage doesn't have?

Comment: @Nam I wasn't aware they had removed vsdbcmd from vs2012. Hopefully you can perform the same operation and mechanics using SqlPackage which at first glance seems to be pretty similar (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: @Kevin SqlPackage seems to be not the same as the GUI tool of Schema Comapre thab the VSDbCmd