# Visual Studio 2013 Data compare tool - Can I schedule this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to automate data comparison and synchronization between two tables. I was thinking of using VS 2013 Data comparison tool but I can't find a way to create a process and automate it. is it possible? if not - are there any tools that allow this?

Since my question has been identified as a possible duplicate, I'd like to clarify a few points that make it different than the suggested question:

1. My question is about the Data compare tool and not about the schema compare tool.
2. My question includes a part about applying changes automatically which I didn't see in the suggested question.

Thank you.

Comment: This post says you can use the command line to execute it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673516/command-line-api-for-schema-compare-in-ssdt-sql-server-database-project

Answer (score 0):

you can't use Visual Studio 2013 Data compare tool for this purpose bu you can :

[Create a Transact-SQL Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187910.aspx) and [Schedule it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms191439.aspx).